# processing a list in python and pick one from "name :value" pair

Tags: python, dictionary

In my python script, "print var1" prints the following output:

```
{'OS_TYPE': 'LINUX', 'MY_SUBTYPE': 'abc', 'BUILD_ID': 'AAA', 'C_ID': '9999'}
```

this is in 'name' : 'value' pair separated by commas.

from this list, I need to pick the value of MY_SUBTYPE,
looking for something like:

```
print var1[MY_SUBTYPE] # to print abc
```

Comment: my suggestion: [learn python the hard way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a [*dictionary*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), not a list. Dictionaries map keys to values; in your case the keys are strings.

Just supply the key; a string literal will do fine here:

```
>>> var1 = {'OS_TYPE': 'LINUX', 'MY_SUBTYPE': 'abc', 'BUILD_ID': 'AAA', 'C_ID': '9999'}
>>> print var1['MY_SUBTYPE']
abc
```

I *strongly* suggest you go read up on Python dictionaries in the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 0):

The keys of your dictionary are strings.  Thus, you need to make the dictionary index a string:

```
print var1["MY_SUBTYPE"]
```

See below:

```
>>> dct = {'OS_TYPE': 'LINUX', 'MY_SUBTYPE': 'abc', 'BUILD_ID': 'AAA', 'C_ID': '9999'}
>>> dct["MY_SUBTYPE"]
'abc'
>>>
```

Currently, you have the index being an undefined variable named `MY_SUBTYPE`.

Also, here are a couple of tutorials you might want to read that explain dictionaries further:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

http://pythonarticles.com/python_dictionaries.html